# Sqlite vacuum of 100 MB empty file creates 100 MB journal

Tags: sqlite

I have an empty 100 MB Sqlite file and depending on which version of Sqlite I vacuum it, it creates a journal file of either 4k or 100 MB (I intercepted the creation with `inotifywait`, and linked to it so I can see it). Both journal modes are `delete`.

In the [release log](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html), I can only find [one hint](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/info/79326d6eece926fd) about vacuum optimization that might account for the change, but I can't really see if that was the cause.

In any event, why would any version of Sqlite create a 100 MB journal to vacuum a 100 MB Sqlite file with *one empty* table?

Versions:

- 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22 f5b5a13f7394dc143aa136f1d4faba6839eaa6dc
- 3.14.1 2016-08-11 18:53:32 a12d8059770df4bca59e321c266410344242bf7b

Edit:

This is how I captured any file that was created:

```
for fil in $(inotifywait -e create . |awk '{ print $3 }'); do ln $fil $fil-linked; done
```

With the newer version, only that 4k journal is made, nothing else.

Edit 2:

Confusing about vacuum is growing. The manual states: "*The VACUUM command works by copying the contents of the database into a temporary database file and then overwriting the original with the contents of the temporary file.*". However, when I use `inotifywait -m .`, I don't see that. All I see is, on both an empty DB and one with data:

```
./ ACCESS testdb.sqlite3
./ ACCESS testdb.sqlite3
./ ACCESS testdb.sqlite3
./ ACCESS testdb.sqlite3
./ CREATE testdb.sqlite3-journal
./ OPEN testdb.sqlite3-journal
./ MODIFY testdb.sqlite3-journal
./ MODIFY testdb.sqlite3-journal
./ MODIFY testdb.sqlite3-journal
./ MODIFY testdb.sqlite3-journal
./ MODIFY testdb.sqlite3-journal
./ MODIFY testdb.sqlite3-journal
./ MODIFY testdb.sqlite3-journal
./ OPEN,ISDIR 
./ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR 
./ MODIFY testdb.sqlite3-journal
./ MODIFY testdb.sqlite3
./ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE testdb.sqlite3-journal
./ DELETE testdb.sqlite3-journal
```

And without journal:

```
./ ACCESS testdb.sqlite3
./ MODIFY testdb.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

The VACUUM operation creates a temporary copy of the database, and then needs a transaction with a rollback journal to write to the actual database. (Even in an empty database, if [secure_delete](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_secure_delete) is enabled, all the empty space must be overwritten, which might have to be rolled back.) So in the worst case, it can need an additional 200 % of storage space.

Vacuuming is not supposed to be done often, so it was not always optimized very much.

Comment: Secure_delete is not on. A temporary copy of an empty database would be empty, I would say. I still don't see why it would do this.

Comment: A temporary copy of the database *file* is just as large.

Comment: See the inotify command in my post: I captured any file that was created. No big file is made.